# How can I find elevation in my iOS application

Tags: ios, geospatial

I am developing an iOS application in which I provide a facility to find the distance, average speed, calories, time etc. according to a walking path.

Now I want to find the elevation of my walking according to distance and speed. I also want to draw the elevation graph of my walking path. I have searched a lot for that but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Refer this link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation

Comment: hey this link can help me but i dnt knw how to integrate it?can u guide me? @anilMotwani

Comment: Refer to the answer I have posted along with the link that returns the elevation as a JSON response once you pass your location (lat, long).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [google elevation api](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation)

It returns the data in JSON format. You just need to add SBJSON to your xcode project. And then send the NSURLReuest in the following manner :

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&sensor=true

Everything from here is just a cakewalk if you know how to parse JSON response :)

Comment: hey i already integrate this and it works well.but m bit worried about usage of google elevation api.Is it create problems if sent more locations requests per day?..wt u say?.

Comment: Refer this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Comment: okk.i think it dosent matter about usage of google elevation api. let i integrate it without any doubt right?.

Comment: Correct. Use it without any tension. :)

Comment: can we discuss more in chat if u have some time? i wanna ask something more regrading elevation

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=37.334390,-122.046450|37.334120,-122.048230|37.332530,-122.055850|37.332420,-122.056530|37.332330,-122.057650|37.332410,-122.059240|37.332610,-122.060380|37.332920,-122.061530|37.334030,-122.064600|37.334200,-122.065280|37.334420,-122.066730|37.334490,-122.068270|37.334460,-122.068840|37.333700,-122.073220|37.333590,-122.074120|37.333560,-122.074940|37.333630,-122.076090|37.333830,-122.077150|37.333990,-122.077760&sensor=false

Comment: just see that I get that response but m confused which elevation i have to display for my walking path in my ios application.can i get the everage of that or what i have to do?.